# every time click login it return me to the login screen

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

every time click login it return me to the login screen

this is my first code to login

```
    <form action="" method="post" name="log">
    <table border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><span style="font-size:18px; color:#039; font-weight:bold;">Login</span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="113">User name</td>
    <td width="120"><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input name="Uname" type="text" id="LogInUname" size="20" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br />
      A value is required.</span></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><span id="sprypassword1">
      <input name="Pword" type="password" id="LogInPword" size="20" />
      <br />
      <span class="passwordRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="newUsers"><a href="index.php?learn_id=88">New user</a></span></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submitid" id="LogInbutton" value="Login" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</form>

<?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submitid'])) {
        $Uname = $_POST['Uname'];
        $Pword = $_POST['Pword'];


            $Uname = stripslashes($Uname);
            $Pword = stripslashes($Pword);
            $Uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $Uname);
            $Pword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $Pword);

            $loginUser = " select * from loginaccess where Uname= '".$Uname."' and Pword='".$Pword."'";

            $loginUserResults=$db->query($loginUser) or die($db->error);

            if($loginUserResults -> num_rows == 1) {
                $_SESSION['log']=1;
            header('Location:index.php?learn_id=12');

                }else{

            header('Location:index.php?learn_id=320');
            }
        }

?>

<?php ob_flush() ?>
```

and this is the other page that it should go to

```
<?php 
session_start();
        if (!(isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log'] != 1)) {
        header ("Location:index.php?learn_id=3");
    }       
?>
```

now please some one tell me why I am every time try to login I return to the login page what is wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**: This line

```
$_SESSION['log']==1; // compare
```

should be

```
$_SESSION['log']=1; // assign
```

**Second**: I don't see the `session_start();` at the very top of your first page (login)

**Third**: Do not use both `stripslashes` and `mysqli_real_escape_string`. The latter is enough (better if you use a PDO).

Comment: Thanks Aurelio De Rosa for this answer sir but still not working after this change

Comment: @YousefAltaf If you need to go to index.php?learn_id=3 when the user is logged, you need to change the if in this if (isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log'] == 1)

Comment: OK please tell me what you mean I can see the page is trying to go to the logged page which is index.php?learn_id=12 not (3) but some how it return back to id=3 and this is the login page I have made all the changes you asked me to do on 1 - 2 not yet 3 still didn't understand it. (do not use both stripslashes) but still redirecting me to the login screen :(

Comment: I mean that if after you find the user is logged ($_SESSION['log'] == 1) and if this is true you want to redirect him to the page "index.php?learn_id=3" you have to change the if.

Comment: want to redirect him to the page "index.php?learn_id=3" sorry it's want to redirect him to the page "index.php?learn_id=12" OK Mr.Aurelio De Rosa I changed my code above please take another look now

Comment: sir you are talking about this one <?php 
session_start();
        if (!(isset($_SESSION['log']) && $_SESSION['log'] != 1)) {
        header ("Location:index.php?learn_id=3");
    }       
?>
at that point I wanted to say if the session is active and the user is logged in so let him see this page else redirect him to id=3 
this is the header of the page that has the hiding content so if the user is logged in he can see it else the page will redirect him to the login screen again asking him to login first

Comment: Thanks a loot Mr. Aurelio De Rosa it was very nice from you to help me sir now it worked fine every thing now is OK.
Thanks again sir and hope to add you to my friends on facebook this is my link there http://facebook.com/yousef.wasti hope to meet you very soon brother

Comment: @YousefAltaf Sorry but I read this just now. Glad to help you. Anyway, I'm sorry but I use just Twitter :)

Answer (score 0):

Call the `session_start();`

```
<?php
 session_start();
   if(isset($_POST['submitid'])) {
        $Uname = $_POST['Uname'];
  ....
   $_SESSION['log']=1; //assign a value
   ...
?>
```

Comment: I got a form in the beginning of my code so I should put this at very top of the page or just put it at the top of my php code

Comment: @YousefAltaf - session_start() method initialize the session data so it must be at top of the php code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgot to type

```
session_start();
```

On the beginning of the login code, right after

```
<?php ?
```

It should look like this :

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Here
    if(isset($_POST['submitid'])) {
        $Uname = $_POST['Uname'];
        $Pword = $_POST['Pword'];


            $Uname = stripslashes($Uname);
            $Pword = stripslashes($Pword);
```

Comment: Axel Isouard Thanks for this fast replay I did but still the same

Comment: Thanks Mr. Axel Isouard for helping me sir

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be `$loginUserResults->num_rows` in your if-statement. You're referring to it as it would be part of `mysqli` class, even though it's part of the `mysqli_stmt` class.

Modify your code as follows:

```
$loginUser = " select * from loginaccess where Uname= '".$Uname."' and Pword='".$Pword."'";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($loginUser);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

And then your if:

```
if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    $_SESSION['log']=1;
    header('Location:index.php?learn_id=12');
}
```

Comment: now it get this error Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\wamp\www\learning\includes\LoginSys.php on line 45
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\learning\includes\LoginSys.php on line 45

Comment: $loginUser = " select * from loginaccess where Uname= '".$Uname."' and Pword='".$Pword."'";
   
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($loginUser);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();

   if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
      $_SESSION['log']=1;
      header('Location:index.php?learn_id=12');
    }else{
     
   header('Location:index.php?learn_id=320');
   }
  }

Comment: Aah... stupid me. Is that all of your login code or is something missing? Where is the `$db`-object created?

Comment: Disregard my answer, it's incorrect but try to find out what is in `$loginUserResult->num_rows` because if `index.php?learn_id=12` is the page you want to reach, it obviously isn't 1.

Comment: so what should the answer is if it is not 1 here I said if the $loginUserResult->num_rows came true and the user is there so login the user to the page which is index.php?learn_id=12

Comment: Could you add the code to your question where you open the database connection?

Comment: sorry but what this will help in here it has nothing to do with this code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. If `$loginUserResult->num_rows` returns 1, you should land on the page you expect. The problem is that it doesn't.